# A matrix is unitary if, and only if, diagonalizable and all eigenvalues are on the unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I would like to know if the class of unitary matrices is the same as the class of diagonalizable matrices who have all their eigenvalues on the unit circle.

Comment: @prospect It isn't. He's asking for some sort of converse too..

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1657310/227073 look this link

Comment: no, a matrix $M$ is unitary iff its SVD is $U S V^*$ where $|S_{ii}| = 1$, in that case $M M^* = U S V^* V S^* U^* = I$. so replace eigenvalues by singular values and it will ok. alternatively, show that as any normal matrix, an unitary matrix is unitary diagonalizable so in fact $V= U$ and $M = U S U^*$ with $|S_{ii}|=1$ iff it is unitary

Comment: The linked question deals with only one direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Every unitary matrix is diagonalizable and the eigenvalues are on the unit circle. However, the converse is not true, since unitary matrices have orthogonal eigenspaces, whereas your condition does not imply this.

As an example, $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ has the two different eigenvalues $\pm 1$, so it is diagonalizable with eigenvalues on the unit circle. However, it is not unitary.